# Trying to read a composite project file from java getting an error as "Unexpected element: CDATA"

Tags: java, maven, soapui, ready-api

Not able to read composite project file from java getting an error as "Unexpected element: CDATA".

```
WsdlTestCase testCase = new WsdlProject("src/test/resources/xml/SoapUI")
                            .getTestSuiteByName("TestSuite 1")
                            .getTestCaseByName("TestCase 1");
```

I also tried to use WsdlProjectPro but getting error as

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/WsdlProjectPro"

.

Please Note: I have added all the Jar in ReadyAPI_HOME/bin/ and READYAPI_HOME/lib to class path but still i get this error. Can someone help.

Used this code to add the ReadyAPI_HOME jars in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-jars</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                       <directory>${basedir}/src/lib</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Include jar file from READYAPI_HOME/bin directory.

Comment: There was only one jar in READYAPI_HOME/bin directory (ready-api-ui-2.3.0.jar) which was also added to the classpath. Still i get the error mentioned above

Comment: Why add the jars using this complicated and non-portable mechanism? Why not just add ReadyAPI jars as a normal dependency?

Comment: READYAPI_HOME/lib directory has a lot of jars, adding them one by one as normal dependency is a tedious job. Do we have any alternate method?

Answer (score -1):

You should try adding below dependency instead.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-soapui</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

You need to add following repository in pom

```
<repository>
    <id>smartbear</id>
    <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
</repository>
```

If you want to use BDD for web service testing, you also can check [qaf-ws-support](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws#qaf-support-ws)

Comment: org.unitils is **not** in that repository! You should also provide some explanation why the OP should add some 3rd party dependency to his project.

Comment: @user861594 I have added the repository but when i use unitils-soapui i get error as "Failed to collect dependencies at org.unitils.soapui:unitils-soapui:jar:1.0.3"